# Unrecognized selector when adding an object to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have a singleton class with a NSMutableArray property to which I want to add objects and remove objects. For some reason I am getting:

```
-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1edf24c0
```

exception when trying to add to it. Here is the relevant code for the interface of the singleton:

```
//outbox item is the type of objects to be held in the dictionary
@interface OutboxItem : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) unsigned long long size;
@end

@interface GlobalData : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *p_outbox;
+ (GlobalData*)sharedGlobalData;
@end
```

The implementation of the singleton:

```
@implementation GlobalData
@synthesize  p_outbox;
static GlobalData *sharedGlobalData = nil;
+ (GlobalData*)sharedGlobalData {
    if (sharedGlobalData == nil) {
        sharedGlobalData = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
        sharedGlobalData.p_outbox = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedGlobalData;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedGlobalData == nil)
        {
            sharedGlobalData = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return sharedGlobalData;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    return self;
}
@end
```

And here is the code that throws the exception:

```
GlobalData* glblData=[GlobalData sharedGlobalData] ;
OutboxItem* oItem = [OutboxItem alloc];
oItem.size = ...;//some number here
[glblData.p_outbox setObject:oItem forKey:...];//some NSString for a key
```

Am I missing something very obvious??

Comment: The error indicates you have an immutable `NSDictionary`, not an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: try `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *p_outbox;` making it to strong/retain

Comment: aha, yes, "copy" was the issue! Silly me.

Comment: The use of `copy` is fine if that is what you really want. But you need to see my answer to make it work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *p_outbox;
```

is creating a copy of that object which you assign to it.
As you are assigning a `NSMutableDictionary` to it, it's creates a copy of `NSMutableDictionary` object which is `NSDictionary` which is not a mutable copy.

So change it to

For Non ARC

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *p_outbox;
```

For ARC

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *p_outbox;
```

Comment: If you are using ARC, you must use `strong` instead of `retain`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *p_outbox;
```

The `copy` semantics of the property result in a copy of the dictionary being made when you assign a value to the property. But the `copy` method for a dictionary always returns an immutable `NSDictionary`, even when called on an `NSMutableDictionary`.

To solve this problem you must create your own setter method for the property:

```
// I'm a little unclear what the actual name of the method will be.
// It's unusual to use underscores in property names. CamelCase is the standard.
- (void)setP_outbox:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary {
    p_outbox = [dictionary mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I need copy, but your explanation is great.