# How to copy correctly a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to copy a NSMutableArray with the code below :

```
SectionArray *newSectionArray = [[SectionArray alloc] init];    
NSMutableArray *itemsCopy = [self.sections mutableCopy];
newSectionArray.sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:itemsCopy copyItems:YES];
```

But I have an error when I try to set an object in this new array :

```
[[self.sections objectAtIndex:intSection] replaceObjectAtIndex:intRow withObject:object];

[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7191720
```

I also tried :

```
SectionArray *newSectionArray = [[SectionArray alloc] init];    
newSectionArray.sections = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:itemsCopy copyItems:YES] mutableCopy];
```

My SectionArray class :

```
@implementation SectionArray

@synthesize sections;
@synthesize value;

- initWithSectionsForWayWithX:(int)intSections andY:(int)intRow {
    NSUInteger i;
    NSUInteger j;

    if ((self = [self init])) {
        sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:intSections];
        for (i=0; i < intSections; i++) {
            NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:intRow];
            for (j=0; j < intRow; j++) {
                Node * node = [[Node alloc] initNodeWithX:i  andY:j andValeur:0];
                [a insertObject:node atIndex:j];
            }
            [sections addObject:a];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setObjectForNode:(Node *)object andX:(int)intSection andY:(int)intRow {

    [[sections objectAtIndex:intSection] replaceObjectAtIndex:intRow withObject:object];
}

- (SectionArray *) copy {
    ...
}
```

@end

Comment: show the SectionArray Class

Comment: And I think SectionArray is not mutable.

Comment: I add the sectionArray class in my post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unrecognized selector when adding an object to NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366894/unrecognized-selector-when-adding-an-object-to-nsmutablearray)

Comment: All my properties are (nonatomic, strong)

Comment: Wait, so you're positive that `sections` isn't declared to copy?

Comment: The problem is not `sections`, but `[sections objectAtIndex:intSection]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I see it correctly then `sections` is a mutable array, but its elements

```
[sections objectAtIndex:intSection]
```

are *immutable arrays*, so you get the exception at

```
[[sections objectAtIndex:intSection] replaceObjectAtIndex:intRow withObject:object];
```

The reason is that you *copy* the items here (`copyItems:YES`):

```
newSectionArray.sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:itemsCopy copyItems:YES];
```

so even if `itemsCopy` is an array of mutable arrays, the copies of these elements are immutable.

*Added:* For a "nested mutable copy" of your nested array you could procede as follows:

```
SectionArray *newSectionArray = [[SectionArray alloc] init];
newSectionArray.sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSUInteger i=0; i < [sections count]; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *a = [[sections objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];
    [newSectionArray.sections addObject:a];
}
```